# UITableView mixing values because of reusable cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a problem when I scroll in my tableview which contains elements that can be scrolled horizontal it is mixing the values.
[image]

[image]

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : RoundWorkoutCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! RoundWorkoutCell

    let tmpCell = cell

    print(tmpCell)

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! RoundWorkoutCell;
    }
    let exerviseName = RoundLabels[indexPath.row]

    if(indexPath.row == 0){

        for countMe in 0..<self.round_1_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition1.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition1.append(115+roundPosition1[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition1[countMe]
        }

    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        for countMe in 0..<self.round_2_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition2.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition2.append(115+roundPosition2[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition2[countMe]
        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 2){
        for countMe in 0..<self.round_3_exercises.count {
            if(countMe<1){
                roundPosition3.append(5)
            }else{
                roundPosition3.append(115+roundPosition3[countMe-1])
            }
            scrollerSize = 115+roundPosition3[countMe]
        }
    }......
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(scrollerSize),115)
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default


    if(indexPath.row==0){

        for index in 0..<self.round_1_exercises.count {
            print("Round position 1 \(self.roundPosition1[index])")

            var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition1[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
            label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition1[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
            label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
            label1.text = exerciseInfo.exercise_name(self.round_1_exercises[index] as! String)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

            let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition1[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
            let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: (self.round_1_exercises[index] as? String)!) as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitle(self.round_1_exercises[index] as? String, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition1[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
            label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = self.round_1_decoration[index] as? String
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)



        }
    }else if(indexPath.row == 1){
        for index in 0..<self.round_2_exercises.count {
             print("Round position 2 \(self.roundPosition2[index])")

            var imageView : UIImageView
            imageView  = UIImageView(frame:CGRect(x:roundPosition2[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 110 ))
            imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(imageView)

            let label1: UILabel = UILabel()
            label1.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition2[index],y: 5, width:110, height: 20 )
            label1.textColor = UIColor(red:17/255.0, green: 22/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha:1.0)
            label1.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label1.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-CondensedLight", size: 14)
            label1.text = exerciseInfo.exercise_name(self.round_2_exercises[index] as! String)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label1)

            let frame1 = CGRect(x:roundPosition2[index]+10,y:25, width:90, height: 90 )
            let button = UIButton(frame: frame1)
            button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
            button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: (self.round_2_exercises[index] as? String)!) as UIImage?, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor.blackColor(), forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitle(self.round_2_exercises[index] as? String, forState: .Normal)
            button.setTitleColor(UIColor(red:0/255,green:0/255,blue:0/255,alpha:0.0), forState: .Normal)
            button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClick:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(button)

            let label: UILabel = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect(x:roundPosition2[index],y: 115, width:110, height: 20 )
            label.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 14)
            label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
            label.text = self.round_2_decoration[index] as? String
            cell.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.addSubview(label)



        }
    }.....
    cell.RoundExercise_Cell_Label.text = exerviseName

    return cell as RoundWorkoutCell
}
```

Here is the custom cell class

```
class RoundWorkoutCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var RoundExercise_Cell_Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView: UIScrollView!


override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Initialization code
    self.RoundExercise_Cell_Label.text = ""
    self.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(0),115)
}
```

I have placed this thread before but no one answered.I need to fix this.I have finished my whole app and this is left.I know that i have to use somehow prepareForReuse() but am not sure how,or if i could disable this reusable cells.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

class RoundWorkoutCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet var RoundExercise_Cell_Label: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView: UIScrollView!





override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Initialization code
    self.RoundExercise_Cell_Label.text = ""
    self.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(0),115)
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    //myOutletName = myNilValue

    self.RoundExercise_Cell_Label.text = ""
    self.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(0),115)

    for subview in RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.subviews {
            print(subview)
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }

    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The cells are reused to save on memory, this means that you need to recycle them properly to stop old data from being shown. You can do this by adding the `prepareForReuse()` function into your tableviewCell. In here you will need to set image outlets to be empty i.e by setting it to `UIImage()`. You will need to do the same with all outlets. This will ensure that old data that is not relevant will not be shown.

Example:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    //myOutletName = myNilValue 
    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

Comment: OK but how to do it can you help me out with this please

Comment: How do i place the value back it just gives me back the value from the prepareForReuse i have tried this i mentoied but i havent got it working properly

Comment: `prepareForReuse` is called before the cell is set. It is in here that you can reset all of your content, ready to for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to populate it.

Comment: I come from a android background.I tried to do it in android way since there is no tutorials on some advanced stuff.Isn't the prepareForReuse calling its self i mean this stuff confuses me a lot.Why isn't it reusing it self like in android but we have to do it.A really dumb solution

Comment: It is being called already but you need to override it to add your outlets etc into it.

Comment: Ok im adding outlets i have done it but the problem is that im creating button in a for loop and add them to the scrollview.And as i see there is no hope in just reloading somehow the views in the scrollview.

Comment: I would personally have made the cells in the storyboard using prototyped cells, then you have references to them already so you can reset those.

Comment: override func prepareForReuse() {
        //myOutletName = myNilValue
        
        self.RoundExercise_Cell_Label.text = ""
        self.RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(0),115)
        
        for subview in RoundExercise_Cell_ScrollView.subviews {
                print(subview)
                subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
        
        super.prepareForReuse()
    }

Comment: There is the solution

Comment: Correct, as my answer states, you need to reset your cell in `prepareForReuse()`. If this has helped then please mark it as the answer :)

Comment: I knew it before but i need someone to tell me how to remove those views from it.I have added an answer already

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to reuse cells, you can simply remove the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Try replacing these lines:

```
var cell : RoundWorkoutCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! RoundWorkoutCell

let tmpCell = cell

print(tmpCell)

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! RoundWorkoutCell;
}
```

With this:

```
cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as! RoundWorkoutCell;
```

This approach doesn't reuse cells and will be less performant and will leak memory.

---

A better approach would be to construct the cells once and then reuse them, instead of rebuilding them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. For example, if you design the cells in the NIB (as you are doing now), there's no need to add buttons and labels again by code, you can simply change the contents and hide those that are not needed.

Then, on `prepareForReuse` (or even at the beginning of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`), you reset the content of the row to the initial state.

Comment: Well its not working it crashes.Its like i need to add this buttons to it but they mix.I cant design like 30-50 buttons than hide them.I need something like in the code but only that can restart them.It adds them good but this happens.So i have a row than in the row buttons which you scrool you can click them,so they peform a segue

Answer (score 1):

@Swinny89 was at right point thank you for that, but I can add more detail about prepareForReuse method. If you remove all your reusing cell data in that method, the performance will reduce. On the other hand, you can hide your variables in prepareForReuse method, and make them visible in your cell init method.

For example as the way I did:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {

    if(commentLabels != nil) {
        for item in commentLabels {
            item.hidden = true
        }
    }

    super.prepareForReuse()
}
```

In other method I make the visible with if check:

```
    if(commentLabels == nil) {
        // creating new labels and adding to commentLabels

    } else { // it means reuse cell data and it has been hidden
        // hidden = false
        for item in commentLabels {
            item.hidden = false
        }

    }
```